# Blazor | Unity | Interacting with camera field of view

Tags: unity-game-engine, .net-core, blazor, webassembly, unity-webgl

I'm currently working on a blazor project,

AND I integrated a build webGl unity.

The container unity is responsive and the HUD in Unity too.

My question is : Is it possible to run my project on mobile? If it's the case :

I would like to modify the field of camera of Unity to fit with mobile device resolution.
There is a way to do it? Maybe with server call ? or wasm api?

Thanks in advance,

P.S here is some Image of the result of the current project and " expected " result.
[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFcL.jpg)
[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCT5o.jpg)

Comment: I am not advicing, just curious. Why mix blazor in? Unity can build your solution almost effortlesly for your different platforms, desktop, mobile and web. Why mix front web development frameworks in such as blazor? What is the benefit of that?

Comment: On the other hand you say that the proyect is a blazor proyect and that then you integrated a unity build in. I was not aware that that was even possible. The same question as before but the other way round, what features do you enhance your blazor web app with by integrating a unity build?

Comment: I am interested in the chance of utilizing some of the unity feateures in other type of apps such as web apps, and I am considering an scenario where I would like to do so. Thats the reason of my questions. I wish I could be of more help and upvote for this intereseting question.

Comment: The goal of this project is to make a " game " linked service like : Buy | Selling for example. My english is not perfect, but this page explains perfectly advantage about mixing those tehcnologies : 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/blog/build-for-the-web-with-aspnet-for-unity-developers/
You also get some advantage of power Blazor + everything is linked at same area for the user and, I hope, one project for mobile and computer device user :)

Comment: I'm currently a bit busy, but i would love to explain you further details if you get interest ; I had a hard time to mixe it first time, but this is not :)

Comment: thanks a lot. Very interesting